# How to fix conversion of a font with fontface.js

Tags: three.js, typeface.js

I need to generate text in a three.js scene. I'm using the `THREE.TextGeometry` class to generate the text.

My problem, as seen below, is that the text has issues with curves.

[image]

You can see that the characters with straight lines renders fine, the characters with curves are messed up.

I've changed the parameters passed in to TextGeometry and can't seem to fix the rendering at all.

Is there a better way to convert a font than using http://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/ or am I doing something wrong with the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Never found an issue - but it might be an issue with the particular font I was using "Montserrat". I've tried various other fonts and have no problem with any others.